# Bootstrap 4 card-deck equal height is not being applied

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My problem is that the property of card-deck (The .card-deck class creates a grid of cards that are of equal height and width. The layout will automatically adjust as you insert more cards.) does not seem to be applying.

This is the code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid"> 
<div class="card-group">
    <div class="card" id="col1m">
        <div class="card-header text-center" style="color: #888" id="display1_title">CAUDAL abcdefghi (BPM)</div>
        <div class="card-body text-center" id="col1">
            <p class="card-text" style="font-family:roboto; font-weight: bold; color:#888" id="display1_value">0</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card" id="col2m">
        <div class="card-header text-center" style="color: #888;" id="display2_title">VOL. TOTAL (BBL)</div>
        <div class="card-body text-center" id="col2">
            <p class="card-text" style=" font-family:roboto; font-weight: bold;   color: #888" id="display2_value"> 0 </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are more closing `</div>` tags than opening `<div>` tags here. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: Actually by checking on https://jsfiddle.net/hftsrk26/ your code it seems to work all as it have to...

Answer (score 0):

You have a closing div at the end of your code with an opening div 
here is your code working fine

https://codepen.io/growload/pen/QWwMybX?editors=1000

```html
<div class="card-group">

  <div class="card" id="col1m"   >
      <div class="card-header text-center"  style=" color: #888" id="display1_title">CAUDAL (BPM)</div>
      <div class="card-body text-center"   id="col1" >    
      <p class="card-text" style=" font-family:roboto; font-weight: bold;  color: #888"   id="display1_value"> 0  </p>
      </div>
  </div>

<div class="card" id="col2m"  >
      <div class="card-header text-center"  style=" color: #888 ; " id="display2_title"  >VOL. TOTAL (BBL)</div>
      <div class="card-body text-center"   id="col2"   >    
      <p class="card-text" style=" font-family:roboto;    font-weight: bold;   color: #888"   id="display2_value"> 0  </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i`m sorry. I add the first line of the code, <div class="container-fluid">.  On the other hand, I did a test with codepen.io and it works fine. I`m goning to do some test to find why it works different when test with server or localhost. Thanks!